# T-SQL function loop

Tags: sql, t-sql, loops, sql-server-2008-r2

I was wondering if I could get some help on a T-SQL function I am trying to create:

Here is some sample data that needs to be queried:

Simplified table:

```
ID|PersonID|ValueTypeID|ValueTypeDescription|Value

 1|ZZZZZ000L6|ZZZZZ00071|Start Prison Date|3/28/2012
 2|ZZZZZ000L6|ZZZZZ00071|Start Prison Date|10/10/2012
 3|ZZZZZ000L6|ZZZZZ00072|End Prison Date  |3/29/2012
 4|ZZZZZ000MD|ZZZZZ00071|Start Prison Date|1/15/2012
 5|ZZZZZ000MD|ZZZZZ00072|End Prison Date  |2/15/2012
 6|ZZZZZ000MD|ZZZZZ00071|Start Prison Date|4/1/2012
 7|ZZZZZ000MD|ZZZZZ00072|End Prison Date  |4/5/2012
 8|ZZZZZ000MD|ZZZZZ00071|Start Prison Date|9/3/2012
 9|ZZZZZ000MD|ZZZZZ00072|End Prison Date  |12/1/2012
```

What I need is a T-SQL function that accepts the `PersonID` and the Year (`@PID, @YR`) and returns the number of days that person has been in prison for that year.

```
dbo.NumDaysInPrison(@PID, @YR) as int
```

Example:

```
dbo.NumDaysInPrison('ZZZZZ000L6', 2012) returns 84
dbo.NumDaysInPrison('ZZZZZ000MD', 2012) returns 124
```

So far, I have come up with this query that gives me the answer sometimes.

```
DECLARE @Year int
DECLARE @PersonID nvarchar(50)

SET @Year = 2012
SET @PersonID = 'ZZZZZ000AA'

;WITH StartDates AS
(
SELECT
Value,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Value) AS RowNumber
FROM Prisoners
WHERE ValueTypeDescription = 'Start Prison Date' AND PersonID = @PersonID AND YEAR(Value) = @Year
), EndDates AS
(
SELECT
Value,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Value) AS RowNumber
FROM Prisoners
WHERE ValueTypeDescription = 'End Prison Date' AND PersonID = @PersonID AND YEAR(Value) = @Year
)
SELECT
SUM(DATEDIFF(d, s.Value, ISNULL(e.Value, cast(str(@Year*10000+12*100+31) as date)))) AS NumDays
FROM StartDates s
LEFT OUTER JOIN EndDates e ON s.RowNumber = e.RowNumber
```

This fails to capture if a record earlier in the year was left without an end date:
for example if a person has only two records:

```
ID|PersonID|ValueTypeID|ValueTypeDescription|Value

 1|ZZZZZ000AA|ZZZZZ00071|Start Prison Date|3/28/2012
 2|ZZZZZ000AA|ZZZZZ00071|Start Prison Date|10/10/2012
```

(3/28/2012 -> End of Year) 
(10/10/2012 -> End of Year)

will returns 360, not 278.

Comment: This is currently "please do my job for me". Have a go at it and come back with any specific questions you have.

Comment: Have you considered start date in 2012 and end date in 2013?

Comment: This is merely part of a query I will have to heavily edit.  I ask it like this because I don't know where to begin.  
How would I loop through all the records, for example?

Comment: The edited code above works, but has some assumptions.. It must have an end date for each start date, the times cannot overlap, and doesnt work if the start date was prior to the beggining of the year.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you have the data that you need to split out your 'start date' values and your 'end date' values. You don't really need to loop through anything, you can just pull out your start values then your end values based on your person and compare them.

The important thing is to pull out all you need to begin with and then compare the appropriate values.

Here's an example based on your data above. It would need some heavy tweaking to work with production data; it makes assumptions about the `Value` data. It's also a bad idea to hard-code valuetypeid as I have here; if you're making a function, you'd want to handle that, I think.

```
DECLARE @pid INT, @yr INT;

WITH startdatecalc AS
(
    SELECT personid, CAST([value] AS date) AS startdate, DATEPART(YEAR, CAST([value] AS date)) AS startyear
    FROM incarctbl 
    WHERE valuetypeid = 'ZZZZZ00071'
),
    enddatecalc AS
(
    SELECT personid, CAST([value] AS date) AS enddate, DATEPART(YEAR, CAST([value] AS date)) AS endyear
    FROM incarctbl 
    WHERE valuetypeid = 'ZZZZZ00072'
)       

SELECT CASE WHEN startyear < @yr THEN DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(@yr AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-01-01' AS date), ISNULL(enddatecalc.enddate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
    ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, startdate, ISNULL(enddatecalc.enddate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) END AS NumDaysInPrison
FROM startdatecalc 
LEFT JOIN enddatecalc
    ON startdatecalc.personid = enddatecalc.personid
    AND enddatecalc.enddate >= startdatecalc.startdate
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 FROM enddatecalc xref 
        WHERE xref.personid = enddatecalc.personid 
        AND xref.enddate < enddatecalc.enddate 
        AND xref.enddate >= startdatecalc.startdate 
        AND xref.endyear < @yr)
WHERE startdatecalc.personid = @pid
AND startdatecalc.startyear <= @yr  
AND (enddatecalc.personid IS NULL OR endyear >= @yr);
```

EDIT: Added existence check to attempt to handle if the same personid was used multiple times in the same year.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated question. It is not so much "asking for a function" as it is dealing with two competing problems. The first is organizing the data, which is transaction-based, into records with start and stop dates for the prison period. The second is summarizing this for time spent within another given span of time (a year).

I think you need to spend some time investigating the data to understand the anomalies in it, before progressing to writing a function. The following query should help you. It does the calculate for all prisoners for a given year (which is the year in the first CTE):

```
with vals as (
      select 2012 as yr
     ),
     const as (
      select cast(CAST(yr as varchar(255))+'-01-01' as DATE) as periodstart,
             cast(CAST(yr as varchar(255))+'-12-31' as DATE) as periodend
      from vals
     )
select t.personId, SUM(datediff(d, (case when StartDate < const.periodStart then const.periodStart else StartDate end),
                                (case when EndDate > const.PeriodEnd or EndDate is NULL then const.periodEnd, else EndDate end)
                               )
                      ) as daysInYear
from (select t.*, t.value as StartDate,
             (select top 1 value
              from t t2
              where t.personId = t2.personId and t2.Value >= t.Value and t2.ValueTypeDescription = 'End Prison Date'
              order by value desc
             ) as EndDate
      from t
      where valueTypeDescription = 'Start Prison Date'
     ) t cross join
     const
where StartDate <= const.periodend and (EndDate >= const.periodstart or EndDate is NULL)
group by t.PersonId;
```

This query can be adapted as a function.  But, I would encourage you to investigate the data before going there. Once you wrap things up in a function, it will be much more difficult to find and understand anomalies -- why did someone go in and out on the same day? How has the longest periods in prison? And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation with test tables and data.  You'll have to change where appropriate.  *NOTE*: i take datediff + 1 for days in prison, so if you go in on monday and leave on tuesday, that counts as two days.  if you want it to count as one day, remove the "+ 1"

```
create table PrisonRegistry
(
    id int not null identity(1,1) primary key
    , PersonId int not null
    , ValueTypeId int not null
    , Value date
)

-- ValueTypeIDs: 1 = start prison date, 2 = end prison date

insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 1, 1, '2012-03-28' )
insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 1, 1, '2012-10-12' )
insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 1, 2, '2012-03-29' )
insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 2, 1, '2012-01-15' )
insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 2, 2, '2012-02-15' )
insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 2, 1, '2012-04-01' )
insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 2, 2, '2012-04-05' )
insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 2, 1, '2012-09-03' )
insert PrisonRegistry( PersonId, ValueTypeId, Value ) values ( 2, 2, '2012-12-1' )
go


create function dbo.NumDaysInPrison(
    @personId int
    , @year int
)
returns int
as
begin

    declare @retVal int
    set @retVal = 0

    declare @valueTypeId int
    declare @value date
    declare @startDate date
    declare @noDates bit

    set @noDates = 1

    set @startDate = DATEFROMPARTS( @year, 1, 1 )

    declare prisonCursor cursor for
    select
        pr.ValueTypeId
        , pr.Value
    from
        PrisonRegistry pr
    where
        DATEPART( yyyy, pr.Value ) = @year
        and pr.ValueTypeId in (1,2)
        and PersonId = @personId
    order by
        pr.Value

    open prisonCursor

    fetch next from prisonCursor
    into @valueTypeId, @value

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @noDates = 0

        -- if end date, add date diff to retVal
        if 2 = @valueTypeId
        begin
            --if @startDate is null
            --begin
            --  -- error: two end dates in a row
            --  -- handle
            --end

            set @retVal = @retVal + DATEDIFF( dd, @startDate, @value ) + 1

            set @startDate = null
        end
        else if 1 = @valueTypeId
        begin
            set @startDate = @value
        end

        fetch next from prisonCursor
        into @valueTypeId, @value
    end

    close prisonCursor
    deallocate prisonCursor

    if @startDate is not null and 0 = @noDates
    begin
        set @retVal = @retVal + DATEDIFF( dd, @startDate, DATEFROMPARTS( @year, 12, 31 ) ) + 1
    end

    return @retVal
end

go

select dbo.NumDaysInPrison( 1, 2012 )
select dbo.NumDaysInPrison( 2, 2012 )
select dbo.NumDaysInPrison( 2, 2011 )
```